# IBM worklight adapter based authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

I have followed [This Link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_adapter_based_authenticator.html)

Which works great for me. I am having 3 adapters in all these three adapter I am using same security test realm for all procedures. After certain timeout which i provided adapter returns me login failed which is correct. But I am getting following error after timeout in application -

**Console error** - AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message: An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule AdapterAuthLoginModule, User Identity Not available.

**Application Error** - handler.handleFailure is not a function

I am not able to get this above error which is in worklight.js

What causes this error? I want to call logout function after timeout. But I cant call because of above error.

**adapter.xml**

```
<wl:adapter xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration" xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="AuthenticationAdapter">

<displayName>AuthenticationAdapter</displayName>
<description>AuthenticationAdapter</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>rss.cnn.com</domain>
        <port>80</port> 

    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2"/>
</connectivity>

<procedure name="submitAuthentication"/>
<procedure name="getSecretData" securityTest="AuthenticationAdapter-securityTest"/>

</wl:adapter>
```

**adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.js**

```
adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
    if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
    return false;
}
if (typeof(response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined'){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
};   


adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response){
    var authRequired = response.responseJSON.authRequired;

if (authRequired == true){
    navigator.notification.alert("Your session has timed out!");


        logoutfunction(); //logout function call



} else if (authRequired == false){

    if(CurrentSessionId == "" || CurrentSessionId == null){

        logoutfunction(); //logout function call
    }
    else{
        var invocationData = {
                            adapter : "API_Adapter",
                            procedure : "storeSession",
                            parameters : [userID],
                            compressResponse : true
                        };

                        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
                            onSuccess : function Lsuccess(res){},
                            onFailure : function Lfaulure(res){},               
                            timeout: timeout
                        });

    }

    adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
   }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide your adapter XML file and challenge handler implementation?

Comment: @IdanAdar hi i have updated... adapter.xml and challenge handler js file. I have used that security test in rest of the adapters. login works but after timout im not getting above errors.

Comment: Where do you declare "CurrentSessionId"?

Comment: First, try to make your submitAuthentication method protected by: `securityTest="wl_unprotected"`. Secondly, it's not very clear what `window.location.hash = "#logout";` is (and why it seems to happen even when doing submitsuccess), or what `CurrentSessionId` is.

Comment: @IdanAdar CurrentSessionId is my global variable which i get after my login method.. when that method get sucess i called submitAuthentication method.

Comment: @NathanH how can i call securityTest="wl_unprotected" which if for unprotectiong my adapter file. I am using method for protecting my adapter. And window.location.hash = "#logout" is for redirecting the page. When authRequired return false then it will redirects you to login page.

Comment: @IdanAdar adan any solution on this?

Comment: You set securityTest="wl_unprotected" on the submitAuthenthentication procedure, not the entire adapter.

Comment: @NathanH wl_unprotected only on submitAuthenthentication procedure of adapter right? i have 3 adapters. So i can set security test on every procedure of each adapter right?

Comment: Do you mean you have 3 different adapters and in each of them you have a procedure for submitAuthentication. There should be only 1.

Comment: @NathanH no no.. only one adapter having submitAuthentication procedure. I am asking that i can set security test on remaining adapters procedures?

Comment: @IdanAdar same error i am getting handler.handleFailure is not a function

Comment: Add the hanldeFailure to your code to your implementation and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73331/discussion-between-suhas-and-idan-adar).

Comment: @IdanAdar continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: @IdanAdar where should i add hanldeFailure ?

Comment: Like so: adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleFailure = ...

Comment: Did the error repeat itself?

Comment: @IdanAdar yes. Every time it goes to that function so i cant write further call in adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleFailure function. Its just now no errors.

Comment: I don't understand... What is the current status? Does it reach handleFailure? What error are you getting now?

Comment: @IdanAdar i am not getting any error now. Its reaching to that function. But what should write in that function means it should redirect to some other function right?

Comment: I would write the error to the log, so you'll see why it's fail... later you can change it like, display a mesasge to that user...

Comment: @IdanAdar sorry for late response.. Yah adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleFailure function getting called many times... so i set flag value after submitAuthentication function success... check that flag value in handlefailure function.. to handle that many times call... is it good way to handle this issue like this way.?

Comment: I am not sure why you're getting it so many times - but if it's working well for you then.... ok. - Please do not keep this question w/out an answer.

Comment: @IdanAdar yah sure will provide my solution over here.. yah its clear that handleFailure wil call every time... yah for me now its working fine.. but if you have any other idea let me know..

Comment: @IdanAdar i added adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.startChallengeHandling() in handlefailure function and in handleChallenge function i checked that flag. hope this does not make any other impact... right? coz functionality working fine.

Comment: Can you write it as an answer instead of a comment/

Comment: @IdanAdar posted my ans. check it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

With help of Idan Adar i got solution

I put below function in adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.js

```
adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleFailure = function(response) {

    adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.startChallengeHandling();

};
```

After calling above function And in adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge i have checked the flag value which I set after getting successful login.